# Vim on debian: cterm=bold doesn't work (using it over ssh with PuTTy as a client)

Tags: vim, ssh

I've been trying to get colourschemes to work properly in VIM (on debian) when using it over ssh with PuTTy as a client (from windows7).

Such code from theme `hi Search cterm=bold` does not work - words are not bold.

I have tried a lot of themes - and I have found no themes with bold words (but using gvim on windows gives me bold words).

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Does `term=bold` work?

Comment: `bold` is only a hint: it's up to your terminal emulator to decide what to do with that: using a bold font, using a brighter color or not doing anything at all.

Comment: `term=bold` does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PuTTY by default represents bold as a brighter color, but you can change that at Change Settings > Window > Colours > [ ] Bolded text is a different colour. From the help:

> **Bolded text is a different colour**
>
> When the server sends a control sequence indicating that some text should be displayed in bold, PuTTY can handle this two ways. It can either change the font for a bold version, or use the same font in a brighter colour. This control lets you choose which.
>
> By default the box is checked, so non-bold text is displayed in light grey and bold text is displayed in bright white (and similarly in other colours). If you uncheck the box, bold and non-bold text will be displayed in the same colour, and instead the font will change to indicate the difference.

Comment: `Bolded text is a different colour` - this was my situation. I changed the setting, and the bold now is really bold (checked with `echo -ne "\033[1mI am bold\n\033[0mI am not\n"`). 

But the words in vim are still not bold.

Comment: What's the value of `$TERM`? For me, it's `putty-256color`, and Vim shows bold just fine.

Comment: Now all is good, thanks - the reason was really `Bolded text is a different colour`